# Pass value from view to another view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application, which want to hide and show divs on one of the Controller view.

So I have a parent View,

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

and a js code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url : '@Url.Action(actionName: "Action1", controllerName: "Controller1")',
    dataType: "html",
    async:true,
    success: function (result) { $("#div1").html(result); }
    });
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url : '@Url.Action(actionName: "Action2", controllerName: "Controller2")',
    dataType: "html",
    async:true,
    success: function (result) { $("#div2").html(result); }
    });

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url : '@Url.Action(actionName: "Action3", controllerName: "Controller3")',
    dataType: "html",
    async:true,
    success: function (result) { $("#div3").html(result); }
    });

});
```

This loads the div with the controller views.But I want to show one div at a time. And each divs staying for 10sec.
Also is there a better way to write the $(document).ready(function ()?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "show one div at a time, each divs staying for 10 seconds".  So run your first ajax, and in the success method, delay the execution of the second ajax by 10 seconds.  In the success of the second ajax call, delay the execution of the third ajax by 10 seconds.

Comment: N.B. `async: true` is redundant - that's the default value. You can remove that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var divs = $(".myDiv");
  var sampleImageList = ["animals", "arch", "nature"];

  // make your ajax calls and insert it into respective div
  var request = function(action, controller, div) {
    var url = "@Url.Action(actionName: " + action + "," + "controllerName: " + controller + ")";
    var index = $(divs).index(div);
    var sampleImage = "<img src=\"https://placeimg.com/640/480/" + sampleImageList[index] + "\">";
    $(div).html(sampleImage);

    /* use ur Ajax call  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(result) {
          $(div).html(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
          $(div).html(status); // handle error here 
        }
      }); */

  };

  var swap = function() {
    var $active = $("#myGallery .active");
    var $next = ($("#myGallery .active").next().length > 0) ? $("#myGallery .active").next() : $("#myGallery div:first");

    $active.fadeOut(function() {
      $active.removeClass("active");
      $next.fadeIn().addClass("active");
    });
  }; // swap end

  divs.each(function(index, div) {
    var action = $(div).attr("data-action");
    var controller = $(div).attr("data-controller");
    request(action, controller, div);
  }); // divs end
  
  $("#myGallery .active").fadeIn(); // show first div
  setInterval(swap, 10000);

});
```

```css
#myGallery .myDiv{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myGallery">
  <div id="div1" class="myDiv active" data-action="first" data-controller="home"> </div>
  <div id="div2" class="myDiv" data-action="second" data-controller="home"></div>
  <div id="div3" class="myDiv" data-action="third" data-controller="home"></div>
</div>
```

We use CSS to hide all our div's.
Right away we will make all the AJAX requests and save it into respective div. Then we use our swap function to show or hide div's. In case of an AJAX error, you could append a placeholder image or show an error message, it is up to you.

https://jsfiddle.net/r958njhq/

Comment: this works for me. But my controllers return images. So when I use the above script it is not a smooth transition between the images/divs. Is it possible to animate the divs/images as they appear? Also if there is a network error I would like to show an error message. At the moment the screen goes blank when there is a network error. Is it possible to have another div with error message and show it when network on client side goes down?

Comment: I have updated the script and html. This should be far smoother than before, as we are making AJAX requests early and only swapping div's with fadeIn and fadeOut. Also added error handling.

Comment: when I tried to add it to my code , this has a bit of an issue. Should the divs.each be inside swap or outside swap? The bracket is not closed before the divs.each

Comment: @liroforum divs.each should be outside swap. I've commented by code above to mark end of swap and divs.each loop function